# JQuery dialog not returning to codebehind

Tags: jquery

I have a div contains confirm dialog(yes and no buttons),which i am opening using below jquery. but i need to go to code behind if yes is clicked and if no no actions should done. I'm trying to return true and false **but its not working**..please help me..

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#<%=Gridview1.ClientID%> #confirm-dialog a[id*=lnkupdate]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Update?")) {
               //if yes button is clicked should go to codebehind
                return true;
            } else {
               //if no button is clicked terminate the operation
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what happens when you click yes/no?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing what code you're using to send the data to code behind.  If this is all the code you have, then it's not enough, you're not sending anything to the server.

My first (and snarky) suggestion is to switch to MVC if at all possible. It's much easier to deal with.

You will either have to send an ajax request to a generic handler (an ashx file) that will process your Yes/No or you will have to submit the entire page to the server.

Posting the whole page to the server with a jquery dialog will be problematic as jquery moves the dialog div tag to the bottom of the page, likely outside of your form tag.  In this case take the value of the Yes/No and set a hidden form field in your form.  (Jquery and WebForms don't get along all that well.)

Lastly, be careful moving things around with jQuery on a WebForms page (or having jquery do it for you with a modal).  It can be very fickle regarding the order of the controls as it posts.